# Inject Provider Service or Container. Good practice

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony

My question is more a doubt about what's the best solution in terms of good practice.

Imagine we need to implement a handler depending in one parameter coming from an entity.
Let me explain

**OPTION1**

- Service/Provider/HSBCProvider
- Service/Provider/BarclaysProvider
- Service/BankHandler
- Controller/BankController

*BankHandler*

```
class BankHandler {
  private $container;
  function __contructor($container) {
    $this->container = $container;
  }
  function create($account) {
    $provider = $this->container->get('service.provider.'.$account->getName());
    $provider->do();
  }
}
```

*BankController Action*

```
public function createAction($id) {
   $account = $repository->getAccount($id);
   $bankHandler = $this->get('service.bank_handler');
   $bankHandler->create($account);
}
```

**OPTION 2**

- Service/Provider/HSBCProvider
- Service/Provider/BarclaysProvider
- Controller/BankController

*BankController Action*

```
public function createAction($id) {
   $account = $repository->getAccount($id);
   $bankProvider = $this->get('service.provider.'.account->getName());
   $bankProvider->do();
}
```

With this option the BankHandler class is not longer needed

I'm simplifying all the logic inside the create and the action.

I don't like Option 1 cos I'm injecting the container.
I don't like Option 2 cos action controller have too much logic (fat controller?).

Any other better solution?

Comment: In your first option, your `BankHandler` class does not necessarily have to depend on the container. Just add a way to register a provider with a name and the return this one in the `create()` method (or apply whatever logic you need there too).

Comment: @xabbuh I don't want to instantiate the provider class in the create method so I have to inject it in to the constructor based on the account name. The provider service is already registered properly

Comment: how bad is this question to have -2?

Comment: You can inject the service but associate a name with it.

Comment: @xabbuh the name is: service.provider.hsbc or service.provider.barclays

Comment: Well, not exactly as I meant it. The name I was refering to would be something that you can use as an internal identifier that should be completely independent of your service ids (take a look at @qooplmao's answer and the the registry  which explains this in much better detail). By the way, peolple likely downvoted your question as it is not a concrete problem but more a discussion about best practices  StackOverflow is not thought for: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: [This](http://jwage.com/post/103724682571/when-to-inject-the-container) is a good read, Symfony still has to instantiate a proxy of the service even if it's not used so if you have many dependencies, just inject the container...

Comment: The first comments by Marco Pivetta are also interesting in that blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a registry service with all of your providers, inject that into the handler and get the provider from that. Something along the lines of...

```
class BankProviderRegistry
{
    /**
     * @var array|BankProviderInterface[]
     */
    private $providers = array();

    public function __construct(array $providers = array())
    {
        foreach($providers as $name => $provider) {
            $this->addProvider($name, $provider);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add provider to registry
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param BankproviderInterface $provider
     */
    public function addProvider($name, BankProviderInterface $provider)
    {
        $this->provider[$name] = $provider;
    }

    /**
     * Get provider by name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return BankproviderInterface
     */
    public function getProvider($name)
    {
        if (!isset($this->providers[$name])) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf('Provider "%s" is not registered', $name));
        }

        return $this->providers[$name]; 
    }
}
```

You could either add these in your services like..

```
app.registry.bank_provider:
    class: AppBundle\Registry\BankProviderRegistry
    arguments:
        - 
            'a name': '@app.provider.a_name' 
            'another name': '@app.provider.another_name'
```

.., in your DI Extension, in a compiler pass, or maybe somewhere else I haven't thought of.

Then you pass this into your handler and get the provider like..

```
class BankHandler
{
    private $registry;

    public function __contruct(BankProviderRegistry $registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function create($account) {
        $provider = $this->registry->getProvider($account->getName());
        $provider->do();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your idea. My only concern is about instantiating lots of providers injecting the registry.

Comment: I don't like this. You'll be instantiating the services regardless of whether they're used or not. Injecting the container and calling the services when needed is better than this.

Comment: @LM94 . then your favorite option is 1?

Comment: Injecting the container is almost never the best approach. Going by your thinking I can only assume that you pass the container into every single service rather than making any real use of the DI system.

Comment: What about tagging providers and lazy? and then injecting this services automatically in to the registry with a compiler pass.

Comment: As I said in the answer, there are a lot of options to add these. You could add method calls in the service definition rather than passing an array, you could create a compiler pass (tagging providers and adding through `addMethodCall`) to do the same. I used the arguments array as a simple example. No matter what happens though, when you get to the point where you instantiate the registry the provider will need to be instantiated too.